# NullPointerException during a performclick()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm doing a unit test of an activity. My activity has a button that calls a simple method (no activities, services or anything else).

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.android.my.test.MyActivityTest.testPerformClick(MyActivity.java:41) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:205)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:195)
>   at
>   android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:175)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)

My test is this:

```
public class MyActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {
    MyActivity a;

    public MyActivityTest() {
        super("com.android.my", MyActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        a = this.getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testPerformClick() {
        a.getButton().performClick();
    }

}
```

And my activity is this.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button = new Button();
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        method();
    }

    private void method() {
        // [...]
    }

    public void getButton() {
        return button();
    }
}
```

Comment: `a` or `a.getButton()` is `null`.

Comment: a.getButton returns null, but should it return the activity button?

Comment: It's useful if you can post compilable code.

Comment: your activity does not compile. `button` is not defined, neither is `button()`

Comment: i edited my post sorry. But i still get nullpoinetexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to change MyActivity to this. Your test is getting a NULL for the method `getButton()`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    private Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        b=new Button();
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        method();
    }

    private void method()
    {
        ...
    }

    public Button getButton()
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use the use the exact code above, still the same problem?

Comment: You've got some other problems then. The NPE is generated because when your test calls `getButton()` it's getting a NULL value back. So then when you test invokes the click function, it throws the NPE. Check to make sure you're building your activity correctly and that you do have a non-null `Button` value for `b`. Put breakpoints in the code to verify.

Comment: I get nullpointerexception whenever i try to return a view element. Why? Can't i use a button from a test class?

Comment: Make sure your `onCreate` methods are being called how you think they should be.